Convert to float, pandas string column with mixed thousand and decimal separators
I have a pandas DataFrame with a column containing strings representing numbers. These strings have mixed formats. Some times numbers use comma as a decimal separator and sometimes a dot. When a dot is used as a decimal separator, that number can contain comma as a thousand separator.
For example:
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'NumberString': [
        '1,234.56',
        '789,012.34',
        '45,678',
        '9,876.54',
        '3,210.98',
        '1,000,000.01',
        '123.45',
        '42,000',
        'NaN'
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I want to convert this column to numeric without losing some of the data due to inconsistent format (commas vs dots). However, using pd.to_numeric with parameter errors='coerce' will drop down some of the number
Python
Is there a way to format all the strings to numbers without loosing them due to format?
What I have tried so far:
>>> df['Number'] = pd.to_numeric(df['NumberString'].str.replace(',','.'), errors='coerce')

NumberString  Number
1,234.56      NaN
789,012.34    NaN
45,678        45.678
9,876.54      NaN
3,210.98      NaN
1,000,000.01  NaN
123.45        123.450
42,000        42.000
NaN           NaN

Desired output:
NumberString  Number
1,234.56      1234.56 
789,012.34    789012.34
45,678        45.678
9,876.54      9876.54
3,210.98      3210.98
1,000,000.01  1000000.01
123.45        123.450
42,000        42.000
NaN           NaN


you should replace by '', not '.'.

Unfortunately it wont work for 42,000 or 45,678. Those and some other numbers use comma as a thousand separator while the rest uses commas it as a thousand separator. That's the problem

Can you be more explicit and provide the full expected output?

Yes, I have edited the question and also added desired output at the end

How can you be sure that 42,000 should be 42 and not 42000?  Do all values always contain a decimal separator?  Equally, if 1,000,000.01 is possible, I assume 1.000.000,01 is possible? (Which your accepted answer won't work for.)

If you have mixed formats, you could first try to str.replace the commas by a dot and convert to_numeric with errors='coerce', then fillna with an attempt converting the commas to empty string:
df['Number'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['NumberString'].str.replace(',', '.'), errors='coerce')
                  .fillna(pd.to_numeric(df['NumberString'].str.replace(',', ''), errors='coerce'))
               )

Output:
   NumberString       Number
0      1,234.56     1234.560
1    789,012.34   789012.340
2        45,678       45.678
3      9,876.54     9876.540
4      3,210.98     3210.980
5  1,000,000.01  1000000.010
6        123.45      123.450
7        42,000       42.000
8           NaN          NaN

what about 1.000.000,01/1.000,01?
If this is desired, then you can use a custom function. Count the number of ./, and decide based on those. If a single . or , and the other has zero or more than 1, then remove the other character and convert. If one of each, use the last one as decimal separator. If more that 1 for each, return NaN (you could also use a try/except to catch all invalid strings).
def to_num(s):
    d = s.count('.')
    c = s.count(',')
    if d<=1 and c != 1:
        return float(s.replace(',', ''))
    if c<=1 and d != 1:
        return float(s.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'))
    if c>1 and d>1:
        return float('nan')
    s2 = s[::-1]
    if s2.index('.') < s2.index(','):
        return float(s.replace(',', ''))
    else:
        return float(s.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'))
        
df['Number'] = df['NumberString'].map(to_num)

Output:
    NumberString       Number
0       1,234.56     1234.560
1     789,012.34   789012.340
2         45,678       45.678
3       9,876.54     9876.540
4       3,210.98     3210.980
5   1,000,000.01  1000000.010
6         123.45      123.450
7         42,000       42.000
8            NaN          NaN
9   1.000.000,01  1000000.010
10     1,000,000  1000000.000
11     1.000.000  1000000.000
12      1,000.01     1000.010
13      1.000,01     1000.010
14     1.2.3,4,5          NaN


Thank you, looks crazy but now I see how it works!

What about 1.000.000,01?

@MatBailie is . actually used as thousands separator? I believe a space would be used if , is a decimal separator. In this case it would always be possible to add more conditions.

Yes, many countries use . for thousands and , for the decimal place. I thought that was the whole point of the question.

@MatBailie fair enough, see update for a more generic solution handling this case ;)

Should note that this assumes a decimal place is always present, else it's impossible to determine if 42.000 / 42,000 should be 42 or 42000 (I've asked the op to clarify, but I think they've gone).

Well there is an intrinsic ambiguity here, you can adept the code for either case, but yes a human decision is required here :)

I think 1.000,001 will incorrectly parse as 1.000001 where as it should be 1000.001 (I'm on my phone, I'm testing with wet-ware)

@MatBailie then better use a custom function with explicit checks (updated).

Splitting in to parts and recombining seems simpler...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78274858/53341  (On a phone, so not hardened to gibberish input.)

The simplest approach I can think of is to split the string on the last occurrence of "," or ".", and assume everything before it is the integer part.
Here are two ways to do that...
import pandas as pd
import re

def parse1(mixed_string: str) -> str:
    """
    Assumes atleast one separator present
    """

    # Split on every "," or "."
    parts = re.split(',|\.', mixed_string)

    # Recombine parts with no separators, except before last part
    return f'{"".join(parts[:-1])}.{parts[-1]}'


def parse2(mixed_string: str) -> str:
    """
    Assumes atleast one separator present
    """

    # Split on last (and only last) "," or "."
    parts = re.split('[,|\.](?!.*[,|\.])', mixed_string)

    # Remove all "," and "." from first part, and enforce "." separator before last part
    return parts[0].replace(',', '').replace('.', '') + '.' + parts[1]


df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "string": [
        '1.000', '1.000,000', '1.000.000,000',
        '1,000', '1,000.000', '1,000,000.000',
    ]
})

df["common1"] = df["string"].apply(parse1)
df["common2"] = df["string"].apply(parse2)

df["numeric1"] = pd.to_numeric(df["common1"], errors='coerce')
df["numeric2"] = pd.to_numeric(df["common2"], errors='coerce')

print(df)

Demo : https://www.online-python.com/NftHzixUeX
Both of those assume that there is at least one "," or "." and that the last one is always a decimal place.  This is because otherwise you can't determine if 42.000 / 42,000 should be 42 or 42000.
If you want to be even safer, you could also check that a thousands separator is followed by exactly three numerals, and that there is only ever one decimal point.  That would then cause the following to not parse, as they are gibberish...
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "string": [
        '1.0.0.0',   # Naively parses to 100
        '1.0,0.0',   # Naively parses to 100
        ',1.0,',     # Naively parses to 10
        '.1,0.',     # Naively parses to 10
        '...1...',   # Naively parses to 1
        ',.,1.,.'    # Naively parses to 1
    ]
})

Gibberish being accepted demo : https://www.online-python.com/Lnok9I3qyi
